# PayPal receipt not showing Description information

Tags: php, paypal

In my PayPal application, using the Express Checkout, when i receive the receipt of the payment, the description is empty.

Here is the string that i pass to the DoExpressCheckoutPayment...

```
$nvpstr='&TOKEN='.$token.'&PAYERID='.$payerID.'&PAYMENTACTION='.$paymentType.'&AMT='.$paymentAmount.'&CURRENCYCODE='.$currCodeType.'&IPADDRESS='.$serverName ;

$resArray=hash_call("DoExpressCheckoutPayment",$nvpstr);
```

If i pass here the L_NAME or the L_DESC values, the amount does not match the order anymore

Can you give me some tips about a possible solution?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I remember that I have a problem with the encoding of the content sent to/received from Paypal. If you don't have any clue, it could worth a shot to ensure that your code works in UTF-8 and your paypal account too (by default, mine wasn't in utf-8) -> https://www.cartloom.com/help/topic/55/setting-paypal-utf-8-encoding-important

Comment: I can't find that option...